# How do I store the dissimilar elements of 'newArray' and 'number' into another array 'notInNumber'?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Here is my code. It is not quite doing what I expected it would do. Can't find the reason why

```js
const number=[5,7,8,9];
const newArray=[];
const notInNumber=[];

for(let x=1; x<=50; x++)
{
  newArray.push(x);
}

for(let a=0; a<newArray.length; a++)
{
  for(let n=0; n<number.length; n++)
{
  if(newArray[a]!==number[n])
  {
     notInNumber.push(newArray[a]);
  }
}
}

console.log(notInNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are checking one element from newArray against one element from numbers before placing it in notInNumbers so in the case when `(newArray[a]===number[n])` n just gets increased by 1 and most probably `(newArray[a]!==number[n])` and newArray[a] gets added to notInNumbers.

You should be checking each individual item from newArray against all items from numbers array before pushing it in notInNumbers.

You can achieve that by declaring a boolean variable, for example, `isFound` inside the first loop that keeps track of whether or not this element exists inside `numbers`, then iterate over `numbers` and if you find `a` and `n` where `newArray[a]===number[n]`, you update `isFound` to show that `a[n]` is inside `numbers`. After your loop over `numbers` has finished, look at `isFound` and if it is `false` then add `newArray[a]` to `notInNumbers`.

Comment: Please I don't totally understand. I just started learning javascript a couple of weeks ago.

Comment: Updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
//I'd much rather use this code. Any thoughts? Thanks for the help.
const number=[5,7,8,9];
const newArray=[];


for(let x=1; x<=50; x++)
{
  newArray.push(x);
}


const newerArray=newArray.filter(elements=>{
return number.indexOf(elements)==-1;
})
console.log(newerArray);

const lowestInteger= newerArray.reduce((first,second)=>{
 return (first<second)? first: second;
})
console.log(lowestInteger);
```

Comment: It works, too, but I'd recommend  you to still understand how to make that functionality without inbuilt filtering functions. Also remember to mark an answer :)

Comment: How do I go about it please?